# Python to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

Attempting to transmit data to a database on the same network which is already accessible through Pi browser. Code below won't work gives the following syntax error...

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

The lines which are giving these errors are;

```
sql = "UPDATE pureo2 SET Left =(%s), Right=(%s) WHERE ID=(%s)"
cursor.execute(sql,(left,right,ID))
```

The table in the database is called `pureo2`, having 4 columns, `ID` and `DateTime` which are controlled by the database, and a left and a right column where user data is entered. I am trying to update ID 2 with the left and right values split from the Arduino sending data via serial...

Looked at other peoples posts on here, thought it was to do with the `(%s)` or the `cursor.execute`. Not quite sure, therefore would appreciate any help or guidance on this :) thank you

```
##Imports
import serial
import mysql.connector

##Decare database values
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="ip here",
  user="username here",
  passwd="password here",
  database = "database name here"
)  
ID = 2

##Start the program
print("Oxygen Mask Monitoring System")

##Serial set up
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

##Wait for serial input from nodes
print("Waiting for input from mask...")
print("")
print("")


while True: 
   line = ser.readline().decode().strip()
   print(line)
   list = line.split(',')

   mask= list[0]
   left = list[1]
   right = list[2]
   reed= list[3]
   sensor1= list[4]
   sensor2= list[5]
   sensor3= list[6]


   cursor=mydb.cursor()
   sql = "UPDATE pureo2 SET Left =(%s), Right=(%s) WHERE ID=(%s)"
   cursor.execute(sql,(left,right,ID))
   print ("Record updated successfully")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove your parenthesis in your sql instruction:

```
sql = "UPDATE pureo2 SET Left =%s, Right=%s WHERE ID=%s"
cursor.execute(sql,(left,right,ID))
```